# how can i fetch a word from json output with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i need to get an output (GELF TCP) from this json output through python and its not in line by line format also

i need the print value of python as **GELF TCP**

```
{u'inputs': [{u'node': None, u'name': u'GELF TCP', u'title': u'gelf', u'created_at': u'2019-02-07T08:20:43.820Z', u'global': True, u'content_pack': None, u'attributes': {u'tls_key_file': u'admin', u'tls_enable': False, u'tcp_keepalive': False, u'tls_key_password': u'admin', u'decompress_size_limit': 8388608, u'tls_cert_file': u'', u'recv_buffer_size': 1048576, u'tls_client_auth': u'disabled', u'max_message_size': 2097152, u'number_worker_threads': 1, u'bind_address': u'0.0.0.0', u'tls_client_auth_cert_file': u'', u'use_null_delimiter': True, u'port': 12201, u'override_source': None}, u'creator_user_id': u'admin', u'static_fields': {}, u'type': u'org.graylog2.inputs.gelf.tcp.GELFTCPInput', u'id': u'5c5bea5bcff47e000999e690'}], u'total': 1}
```

Comment: FYI, that's not json. Looks more like a dictionary

Comment: i got this from an api call python output, now i want to fetch a word(GELF TCP) from this through python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just access it with:

```
json_loads_response = json.loads(<your_json_string>)
json_loads_response['inputs'][0]['name']
```